# Is there anyway to use Entity Framework in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core

I've just changed to the new ASP.NET 5 platform. I use visual studio code as my default IDE, and DNX for execution. .NET Core is now by default but I need to switch to .NET Framework always I want to reference the *System.Data.Entity* namespace or the *TodoContext class*.

**Is there anyway to use EF in .NET Core?**

This is what I'm doing now.
[image]

Comment: Some (or all) of Entity Framework moved out of System.Data and into NuGet packages.

Comment: You shouldn't use Asp.Net 5 for any public applications at this point.  It does not have a Go Live license yet, and **ONLY** Entity Framework 7 is supported, which is still in Beta state.  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/releases/tag/7.0.0-beta4

Comment: I'm totally agree with you @Claies, I'm just gathering info for a future migration... Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The EntityFramework in `System.Data` is version 6.
If you want to use .NET Core then you need to switch to EF 7 which no longer lives in System.Data but in the `EntityFramework.*` nuget packages.

Here is an example: https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/project.json#L15

Comment: .NET Core RTM does support EF6.  Not sure when EF6 support was added but it's there now. Tutorial [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html).

Comment: @David ASP.NET Core is not .NET Core. That link is about ASP.NET Core running on the full desktop .NET Framework.

Comment: That link is broken