# How To Resolve Reference Error While Using Entity Framework AndWebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to this and running into some trouble.  I've created a new project in VS2015 - a 'ASP.NEt 5 Preview Template' Web API.  Then I used the Package Manager Console to add Entity Framework (Install-Package EntityFramework)

Then I tried creating a context class that inherits from DbContext.

I'm getting errors on my 'using System.Data.Entity' line.  When I mouse over it, it tells me that it is available for DNX 4.5.1 but not DNX Core 5.0  Resharper also identifies the line as invalid.

> 'The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) BuildWatcherAPI.DNX
>   Core 5.0

I've tried manually adding references to System.Data/System.Data.Entity but that doesn't seem to do the trick.  Clearly I'm doing something very wrong - can anyone point me in the right direction?

What's extra strange is that I've done this from scratch again, and that solution seems to build fine.  So I must have done something else, inadvertently, but I'm having trouble seeing any differences between the two solutions and I'd like to understand what went wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to delete bin and obj folder, then clean+rebuild the solution again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either remove the "dnxcore50" line from your `project.json` because [EF6 doesn't support .Net Core or upgrade to EF7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/07/20/announcing-net-framework-4-6.aspx#entity-framework).

[This answer gives more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30157560/425565)

Answer (score 0):

Which framework version are you using? I'd say that you may change your framwork version to 4.5 and rebuild your project. I say this because I had similar probles few weeks ago and all was because of this.

I'm not really sure but EF dll's have some tricks, some code using framework 4 works with EF 5 (which is supposed to be used with framework 4.5) and some code doesn't and I'm not really sure why...

So, in order to fix it try to change your project to use .Net framework 4.5 (and EF v5)

Hope it helps.